# rbind in a loop in R

Tags: r, loops, rbind

I have `n` data.frame which I want to combine with reputation, where I choose 2 of them.

Lets say I have three data.frame named `data1`, `data2` and `data3`. I want to combine them with `rbind`, so I have: `data1data2`, `data1data3`, `data2data1`, `data2data3`, `data3data1` and `data3data2`.

Instead of writing:

```
data1data2 <- rbind(data1, data2)
...
data3data2 <- rbind(data3, data2)
```

Is there a way which I can do that with a loop in R?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code will build all the combinations of data frames `rbind`ed 2 at a time.

```
for (i in 1:n) {
 for (j in 1:i) {
  if(i==j) { next }
  df_first = paste0("data",i)
  df_second = paste0("data",j)
  expr_rbind = paste0("rbind(",df_first,",",df_second,")")
  expr_store_as = paste0(df_first,df_second)
  expr_final = paste0(expr_store_as," = ",expr_rbind)
  eval(parse(text=expr_final))
 }
}
```

To get permutations instead of combinations, change the loop of `j` in the inner loop from 1 through `n` instead of 1 through `i`.

Answer (score 0):

You can do:

```
data1 <- BOD; data1$demand <- data1$demand +100
data2 <- BOD; data2$demand <- data2$demand +200
data3 <- BOD; data3$demand <- data3$demand +300
L <- list(data1, data2, data3)

combn(L, 2, simplify = FALSE, FUN=function(x) list(rbind(x[[1]], x[[2]]), rbind(x[[2]], x[[1]])))
```

or (to flaten the list):

```
R <- combn(L, 2, simplify = FALSE, FUN=function(x) list(rbind(x[[1]], x[[2]]), rbind(x[[2]], x[[1]])))
do.call(c, R)
```